# How to wait for non-blocking API function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback, async-await

I am using this API function which I can not change:

`xMotor.ccw().step(1, function() { /*callback*/ });`

It serves to control a stepper motor which should physically turn the motor a certain amount of steps. Now I need to turn this motor until a button physically gets pressed and I want to measure the travelled `length`. I went about this like so for now:

```
var length = 0;

async function initialize(){

    while (motor.checkButton(buttonPin)) {
        xMotor.ccw().step(1, function() { /*CALLBACK*/ });
        length++;
        await sleep(10);
    }
}

function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

But since this API function is non-blocking my length variable gets way to many counts. In reality the while loop is way to fast for physically moving the motor one step. I could just increase the `sleep` value but this really does not seem like a good solution and the movement of the motor gets very jittery.

All I/O signals are running from a Arduino. And I'm using the Johnny-five framework.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See the linked question's answers. Basically, you do the same thing you did with `setTimeout`: Create a wrapper that provides a promise, then `await` it.

Comment: So would this be right?
```function makeOneStep(){
    return new Promise(function(){
        xMotor.ccw().step(1, function(){
        })
    })
}```

Comment: Please see the linked question's answers.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I did see the linked answer and I did take my solution from the linked answer. I just want to make sure Im understanding it right. Because my API callback function does not have any `err` or `data`parameters, so I am a little confused.

Comment: I suggest really having a good read, you've left out the `resolve` parameter to the promise callback, which you need because that's how you resolve the promise (again, just like your `setTimeout` above).